# Output band reflectance from Sentinel in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I want to get the reflectance of multiple points，including all bands of sentinel-2. I just contacted GEE and I don’t know how to import GPS points in batches and extract the sentinel reflectivity. I want to get Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-2A reflectivity.

Below is my script:

```
var rawCol = S2.filterDate("2017-1-1", "2019-12-31")
               .filterBounds(roi);
//method 3
var rawLayer = null;
var computedIds = rawCol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['system:index'])
                        .get('list');
computedIds.evaluate(function(ids) {
  print("computedIds ", ids);
  var total = ids.length;
  var showTitle = ui.Label("", {fontWeight: 'bold'});
  var curIndex = 0;
  var bPlus = ui.Button("+", function() {
    curIndex += 1;
    if (curIndex >= total) {
      curIndex = 0;
    }
    showTitle.setValue(ids[curIndex]);
    showSelectRawImage(ids[curIndex]);
  });
  var bReduce = ui.Button("-", function() {
    curIndex -= 1;
    if (curIndex < 0) {
      curIndex = total - 1;
    }
    showTitle.setValue(ids[curIndex]);
    showSelectRawImage(ids[curIndex]);
  });
  showTitle.setValue(ids[curIndex]);
  showSelectRawImage(ids[curIndex]);
  var main = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label('click "+" or "-" to move time window', {fontWeight: 'bold'}),
      bPlus, bReduce,
      ui.Label("select date: ", {fontWeight: 'bold'}),
      showTitle
    ],
    style: {width: '200px', padding: '8px'}
  });
  ui.root.insert(0, main);
 
});
 
function showSelectRawImage(key) {
  if (rawLayer !== null) {
    Map.remove(rawLayer);
  }
  print("show raw image id is: " + key);
  var image = ee.Image(rawCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", key)).first().divide(10000));
  rawLayer = Map.addLayer(image, {bands:["B4", "B3", "B2"], min:0, max:0.3}, key);
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ffengfalai%2Fgee01%3Atest%20point